# HTC Touch Dual as Telstra Modem

Tags: modem

Our CEO has a HTC Touch Dual and he wants to use it as a modem for his laptop. I have setup different phones with different carriers with success - but with some very specific details (as in the network connections setup on the laptop takes carrier specific details).

I have tried for the last 2 days to get through to Telstra (in Australia) to find out these details - but cannot get a straight answer from anyone.

Does anyone know the configuration setup for the PC side of the device? The HTC is already setup with a Data Pack and can connect to the internet fine - so I just need the PC side config.

Thanks.

Comment: Pleeeeeeease someone help me - Telstra suck!

Comment: Telstra! Hah! Just be glad it's not a blackberry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program you're maybe looking for is WmWifiRouter 1.20, it enables you to use your phone as a WiFi -> USB adapter...

I can confirm that it works fine on a HTC Touch Cruise but still can't figure out over a Touch Dual. Sorry about that!

There's an internet sharing option in Windows Mobile 6. Connect to the wifi network using the HTC and configure the internet sharing options. Then connect the cell phone to the PC via USB and the PC should be able to access the net via the HTC's wifi connection.

Hope that will help!

Let me know!

Regards,
David.

Comment: Active Sync installed the drivers necessary, and there is software on the PDA itself to connect internet sharing.

Comment: So you confirm that it works fine?